# Google Charts X-Axis Range

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using google charts to display data from a MySQL database.

I'm taking the data from the database and trying to display it as a column chart. The X-Axis is Dates and the y is just a number. My problem is that the chart only shows a limited range across the x-axis. I was wondering how I can force it to show the full range.

I've seen something that would work well from the link below but not sure how to go about implementing it.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter

Below is the code for the chart.

```
<html>
   <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the chart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'AAA Chart',
           hAxis: {title: 'Date Range', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
        };
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      // Do not forget to check your div ID
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style= "height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE of JSONTABLE OUTPUT:**

```
{"cols":[{"label":"DATE","type":"string"},{"label":"EDGE_UL_BYTES","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":31992929}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":68196}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":199548}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":721885}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":11014811}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":6421541}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":17879277}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":20617431}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":9223382}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":23846636}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":8673057}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":404263}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":1701327}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":20487755}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":78766788}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":31224441}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":11631329}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":53915484}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":59496722}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":275471}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":499141}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":25428}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":408333}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":239719}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":1011}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":9635356}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":8530768}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":6820295}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":10504372}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":3029379}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":39185261}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":16716591}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":9563651}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":5915254}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":8364518}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":2530418}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":5124739}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":13484351}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":23480432}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":59261589}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":8735928}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":8691840}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-02"},{"v":35925299}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":14893025}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":265521}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":154733}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":454987}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":85606}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":832621}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":7448416}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":1585482}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":12355246}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":482326}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":41934565}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":961632}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":1904932}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":45099555}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":126441525}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":31462503}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":5397186}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":15443548}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":11834152}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":10134366}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":9071243}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":4571316}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":13525261}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-03"},{"v":1086730}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":561556}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":466348}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":370119}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":354229}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":593890}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":1360350}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":1013796}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":5372523}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":387304}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":1062974}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":759283}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":1245568}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":28373494}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":87596018}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":2605097}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":4567000}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":9807025}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":38401217}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":9442389}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":63648969}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":10340130}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":386373}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":21895878}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-04"},{"v":1663351}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":1201083}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":204630}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":7532}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":115802}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":3593}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":148789}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":19695492}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":13622356}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":5654365}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":3735165}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":16178999}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":1023789}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":9052454}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":15674098}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":1214709}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":7285801}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":41711340}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":49162494}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":123096997}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":62523914}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":32951013}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-05"},{"v":1184023}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":1748769}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":583821}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":2960417}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":344784}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":1256850}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":623208}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":293669}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":1988185}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":1243333}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":2574596}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":11603265}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":4652272}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":10981397}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":146013414}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":17417450}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":5232282}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":3601553}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":1274695}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":6282462}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":20404608}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":14062545}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":80700894}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":4957796}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-06"},{"v":178627787}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":1862637}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":2035761}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":867915}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":2155872}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":967798}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":315303}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":1564524}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":1243700}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":6182333}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":3915213}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":2604695}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":60858698}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":28802407}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":75384603}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":3881226}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":24181828}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":68974797}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":22285290}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":23282269}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":13613620}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":12973729}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":21961916}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":10189593}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-07"},{"v":13426298}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":1088089}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":197251}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":71947}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":213877}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":5394242}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":19512924}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":28642395}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":17777456}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":13896759}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":10845162}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":36116902}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":22805455}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":52549790}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":21160359}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":32631051}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":20851637}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":10461971}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":149378128}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":259388611}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":403046829}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-08"},{"v":384108324}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":2968585}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":467422}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":426920}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":2477675}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":29465446}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":1205987}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":3307341}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":4647709}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":3115138}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":4392595}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":7605640}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":3977436}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":49787820}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":24348753}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":217612897}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":3245182}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":4027458}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":30008586}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":230455434}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":24893796}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":12001710}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-09"},{"v":33462334}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":4360908}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":4772442}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":2234237}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":683302}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":2065269}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":2203447}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":400460}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":2481043}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":2959639}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":3765713}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":3249979}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":1415904}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":50349145}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":7456001}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":22721511}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":12913444}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":2311915}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":4040401}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":20178350}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":25981064}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":19980249}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":6861088}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":602196}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-10"},{"v":30725925}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":5484475}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":875225}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":337588}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":11162199}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":72766263}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":194011848}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":48199739}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":9134419}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":1908954}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":406013}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":46708}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":80122}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":6630887}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":5841709}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":32018661}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":186873833}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":75675654}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":9798935}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-11"},{"v":3844364}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":2807038}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":7393930}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":1495281}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":5039717}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":1323735}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":696335}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":5380433}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":5317058}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":1620}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":1822798}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":1388524}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":4887410}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":9567978}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":965582}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":38590062}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":258127}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":979923}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":1124552}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":586358}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":2513481}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":62549232}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-12"},{"v":2767879}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":128310}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":5696047}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":2263644}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":218384}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":144994}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":72437}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":223487}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":6304715}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":1588642}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":6068615}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":7434478}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":5013285}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":25186192}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":2854973}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":54801029}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":38196811}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":6132214}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":249771}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":1471703}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":1935058}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":3034072}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-13"},{"v":501284}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":1710831}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":29879}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":64507}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":2282239}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":3597280}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":2616777}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":751727}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":28943892}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":5331544}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":7550324}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":2817309}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":67669388}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":25208741}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":1318805}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":355985}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":103706}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":1851771}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":94186038}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":25493131}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":2700069}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":2179756}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":1900570}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-14"},{"v":15775064}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":8492480}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":18560}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":30736}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":69051}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":64849}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":11817}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":387937}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":389869}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":48804}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":6206586}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":9461886}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":11771910}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":20107871}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":3316824}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":45272882}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":65031592}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":2946967}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":6888402}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":996980}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":11011479}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":1454528}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":1407682}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-15"},{"v":39380371}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":705696}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":2357226}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":2187110}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":3928640}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":1511}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":21421}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":1379}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":1063750}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":30342}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":5688003}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":153183089}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":17110047}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":8516035}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":47822045}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":9335441}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":12238085}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":10551206}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":1668575}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":6991993}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":14285739}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":774661}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":1363246}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-16"},{"v":155690}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":1155390}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":346597}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":6616595}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":31777}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":187}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":0}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":352548}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":13848067}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":13733198}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":14066070}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":13561629}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":17273117}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":40471904}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":6691618}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":38575267}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":35639741}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":56983278}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":23346948}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":28791086}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":28425022}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":53583033}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":8915421}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-17"},{"v":33670318}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":16944809}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":6617325}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":13482879}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":2200389}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":4946450}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":670266}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":915511}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":4677166}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":68787940}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":4810067}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":14175726}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":9278511}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":29882657}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":691843}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":1294517}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":18146091}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":10110975}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":210635}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":3118173}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":8901489}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":1953}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":1612175}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":19688429}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-18"},{"v":8887426}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":6431591}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":316357}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":21074729}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":737732}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":73183}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":280180}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":153678}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":968582}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":7603479}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":2839518}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":43716045}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":21756114}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":3100354}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":10086056}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":8428189}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":1961779}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":2488550}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":3889856}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":7328640}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":3738800}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":18191952}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":3324064}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":13219906}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-19"},{"v":580465}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":3646320}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":157918}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":58140}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":93980}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":449722}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":2173739}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":222989}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":4655290}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":1966493}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":26706903}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":3175047}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":19378870}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":2829665}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":10324354}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":8682420}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":16399630}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":19133397}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":25076182}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":3109994}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":12700945}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":79179686}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":17254564}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":24204355}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-20"},{"v":44773062}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":384079}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":295346}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":296066}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":226195}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":306178}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":439617}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":167606}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":181351}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":1003463}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":1623341}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":30972255}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":4264235}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":10340141}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":2717675}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":8893256}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":23230258}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":2093206}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":49327045}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":45622205}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":19943900}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":16862557}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":72200576}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":15182356}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-21"},{"v":64070319}]}]}
```

Comment: By default, the chart should show the entire data set, so if it is not, there is possibly a problem with your data.  Update your question with the output from `<?=$jsonTable?>` and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @asgallant Here is a sample of the output: {"cols":[{"label":"DATE","type":"string"},{"label":"EDGE_UL_BYTES","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":31992929}]},{"c":[{"v":"2014-01-01"},{"v":68196}]}. It runs from 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-31 but the google chart only shows from 2014-01-01 to 2014-01-19.

Comment: I need to see enough of the data to reproduce the problem in order to help you diagnose this.  Can you update your question with a sufficient number of rows of data in the JSON string to show the problem?

Comment: @asgallant I have added more of the output in the post. The date shows 24 times as its for every hour.